# Unhandled exception during deployment process

Tags: r, shiny

I've recently been developing an app, and noticed a few days ago I updated R to 4.1.2.  After making some changes to the app, I used the Publish button to deploy to shinyapps.io. The deployment console threw the following error and failed:

`Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1045191965 failed: Error building image: R version 4.1.2 currently unavailable`
`Execution halted`

Now, I've deployed many times previously, and this was the first deployment since the update to R.  I haven't included any code because my app.R is over 1500 lines and it really didn't seem to be related to any of thee changes I made.  I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out whether this error is referring to my system or the server I am deploying to.  I expect I may have to roll back to the pre-update snapshot and try again, but I'd like to avoid doing that if the problem lies somewhere else.

Rstudio is Version 1.4.1103

**Operating system:**

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After checking with shinapps.io support, they informed me their server has not been updated to 4.1.2 and to downgrade until they are able to make the upgrade.  They were not able to provide an ETA on that.  Thanks to the support staff there!